# error 500 with express js routing after on form submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, express, facebook-messenger-bot

I've been working on a messenger chatbot that recommends songs based on the mood of the user and I am stuck on routing a reply to the user after the HTML form for preferences has been filled out...

my HTML code only consists of a form that starts as: 
`<form action="/postback" method="get">`

in my index.js file, i check for the endpoint using: 
`app.get('/postback', (req, res) => {`

this always results in a 500 Internal Service Error in console. Would really appreciate some advice on why this may be happening.

EDIT:
here are other relevant parts of my code:

```
const
  request = require('request'),
  express = require('express'),
  body_parser = require('body-parser'),
  path = require('path'),
  app = express().use(body_parser.json()); // creates express http server
```

here is an image of my file system:
[filepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdLIV.png)

Comment: can you post the rest of the code for that route handler?

Comment: added some more code and image of file path

Comment: check for syntax errors. When a server side script errors (such as E_ERROR in PHP), a 500 error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method to POST. I do believe get doesnt send a request body. Forms should post data not get.

Comment: I changed it to post, but now I am getting a 404 Error (Not Found)...

Comment: Save the input in state. And send the response via a function thats referenced by the forms onSubmit event.